# UICollectionView display different cells depend orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to set width of `UICollectionViewCell` depend of the screen width. When it in portrait mode I want to show 3 cells and if in landscape I want to show 4 cells.

I also want to have some padding between cells, but this code below does not help me:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 0, 20);
}
```

I supposed it should add padding at the top, left and right of cell.

If I see portrait mode then:

```
***cell*** *padding* ***cell*** *padding* ***cell***
```

If landscape:

```
 ***cell*** *padding* ***cell*** *padding* ***cell*** *padding* ***cell***
```

So the padding should be every time the same size for different orientation.

Let's say it should be 20pt

Also I want to add 20 pt padding above each cell.

Should I write some custom flow layout?

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3:

1. create an @IBOutlet with your UICollectionView (mine is called picCollectionView)
2. put this code in your viewDidLoad

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3 - 2

   let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
   layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
   layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2
   layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2

   picCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
   ```

   }
3. the number of columns across will change automatically with the device orientation
4. you can adjust the padding by altering minimumInteritemSpacing and minimumLineSpacing

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should invalidate the layout when the orientation/size class changes:

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];

    if (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection.horizontalSizeClass) {
        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    }
}
```

Then adjust the value you return in `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:` appropriately (I've picked random values here):

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    if (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact) {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 0, 20);
    } else {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 40, 0, 40);
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, but the problem that I have to much spacing between cells horizontally, I would like to have for example spacing between cells the same size every time, let says 20 pt, so even if I rotate screen I just should increase size of cell per one row from example from 3 cells to 4 cells. so padding like I displayed every time should be the same. I just need to stretch cells.